# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre estas dos asignaciones de puntero?

Tags: c, punteros

Hoy he estado haciendo un programa en el cual una función devolvía un valor puntero que luego de guardarse en una variable, se imprimia.

El código original era este:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int * fun(int []);

int main(void){
    int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int * ptr = NULL;
    * ptr = fun(arr);
    printf("%d", *(ptr+3));
    return 0;
}

int * fun(int arr[]){
    return arr;
}
```

Debido a que esto me daba una alerta (`file.c:8:8: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`), probé a cambiar la línea 8:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int * fun(int []);

int main(void){
    int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int * ptr = NULL;
    ptr = fun(arr);
    printf("%d", *(ptr+3));
    return 0;
}

int * fun(int arr[]){
    return arr;
}
```

Ahora funciona sin dar alertas, pero no entiendo muy bien como ha funcionado el cambio.

¿Alguien me lo podría explicar?

Gracias y saludos :)

Comment: `ptr` apunta a `NULL`, si despues intentas desreferenciar el puntero, es un comportamiento indefinido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es lo siguiente, En lenguaje C, al trabajar con apuntadores, te brinda dos operadores:

**(&) operador de dirección:**
Este operador te sirve para acceder a la dirección en memoria de la variable a la que se antepone. Por ejemplo, **&nombre = dirección en memoria de la variable nombre.**

**(*) operador de indirección:**
Este operador te permite acceder al valor de la variable a la que apunta el apuntador, "valga la redundancia". Por ejemplo, ***p_nombre = "John Doe".**

Para inicializar un apuntador debes hacerlo sin el operador de indireccion (*)
por ejemplo:

```
ptr = fun(arr);
```

de esta forma el apuntador guarda la dirección en memoria del apuntador que regresa la función, es decir: **"Apunta a lo que devuelva la función"**, cuando lo haces de la siguiente forma:

```
int * ptr = NULL;
*ptr = fun(arr);
```

Lo que estas haciendo es declarar e inicializar el apuntador como nulo, y luego tratar de ingresar el valor que retorna la función dentro de la variable a la que apunta *ptr, pero como fue declarado nulo, no hay un lugar en memoria a donde asignar ese valor. Es por esa razón que el compilador te genera errores.

```
int *ptr;
int var = 100;

ptr = &var;

ptr = direccion en memoria de var
*ptr = valor dentro de var = 100

ptr y &var son equivalentes
*ptr y var son equivalentes
```

Mi explicación fue algo larga y detallada, sin embargo espero que te sirva!

Comment: `int* ptr = func(arrr)` **no** apunta a la función. Lo que sucede es que la función devuelve un resultado en forma de dirección de memoria y dicha dirección se almacena en `ptr`... pero lo que devuelve no es la dirección de memoria de la función. Los punteros a función tienen una forma un tanto diferente.

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu observación, veo que desconozco un poco en esa parte pero seguiré aprendiendo, gracias por compartir tu conocimiento.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa es que cuando escribes `*ptr`, estás pidiendo trabajar no sobre el apuntador sino sobre el valor *apuntado* (es decir, el entero apuntado por `ptr`), que en ese momento ni si quiera tiene espacio de memoria reservado, de paso.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias :)